# Functions to return week first date and week last date in current month

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I created a function to get first date of week as Thursday in MS Access form and reports, but it function returns first day of week in last month.

I need it to return only current month dates. If current week first day is in last month then return first day of week as first date of week in current month.

Current output

When 1-10-2018 is selected from date picker it returns 27-09-2018, which is first date of week in last month but I need it will return first of month which is selected in textbox.

```
Function GetFirstofWeek(dtDate As Date)
    GetFirstofWeek = DateAdd("d", dtDate, -(Weekday(dtDate)) + 1)
         ' Excel formula for this function which is perfect and may be converted to function as required ‘=MAX(B2-WEEKDAY(B2,14)+1, EOMONTH(B2, -1)+1)
    GetFirstofWeek = DateAdd("d", dtDate, -(Weekday(dtDate, vbThursday) - 1)) 
End Function
```

For last day of week

```
Function GetLastofWeek(dtDate) as date
    '=MIN(B2+(7-WEEKDAY(B2,14)), EOMONTH(B2, 0))
     ‘this excel formula return date as I need. 
      GetLastofWeek = DateAdd("d", dtDate, (7 - (Weekday(dtDate, vbWednesday)) + 1)) 

End Function
```

In this function last date of week must be in current month, if month end on first date of then week will be closed and last date of week will be first date of week or days remaining in current week.

Comment: Just check if returned month is the same as selected. If not select the first day of current month (hint: DatSerial). The same for lasr day of month (search for this).

Comment: Current output of this function is as below: 1st week = 27-09-2018 - 3-10-2018, but I want as I select any date  from last month week, it close week on 30-09-2018 and not show next month weekdays and as I select any  date from next month week days ie. 2-10-2018, it will show only days of week of current month like 01-10-2018 to 03-10-2018, same requirement for week lastday function.

Comment: As I said check the result of the Dateadd, for equal month with the selected (dtDate), if they are not equal return the first/last day of the selected month, instead of the Dateadd result, what can be easy found by query the www for "ms access first day of month" or ".... last day of month".

Comment: =MAX(B2-WEEKDAY(B2,14)+1, EOMONTH(B2, -1)+1) this formula in excel works perfect to show result as I need, I am unable to covert this formula to access vba or access expression. Because access dont have eomonth function and not support max function in vba an not in expression.

Comment: '=MIN(B2+(7-WEEKDAY(B2,14)), EOMONTH(B2, 0)) this formula for last day of week also work perfect for result required by me, but I am unable to covert this to access vba function, have you any idea how to covert these formula to functions.

Comment: urdearboys answer is close and shows how to check for the dates to be changed. Instead of Worksheetfunction, this can be done with DarSerial. Search for that.

Comment: urdearboys answer is back and improved. I suggest you to learn how to get first/last day of month  with DatSerial an replace the `Worksheetfunction` with  Make it an answer then. Don't forget to vote and accept urdearboys answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your requirements, consider the following two functions:

**First of Week**

```
Function FirstOfWeek(datRef As Date) As Date
    If Day(datRef) >= Weekday(datRef, vbThursday) Then
        FirstOfWeek = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(datRef, vbThursday), datRef)
    Else
        FirstOfWeek = DateAdd("d", 1 - Day(datRef), datRef)
    End If
End Function
```

*Some examples*:

```
?FirstOfWeek(#2018-10-04#)
04/10/2018 

?FirstOfWeek(#2018-10-10#)
04/10/2018 

?FirstOfWeek(#2018-10-11#)
11/10/2018 

?FirstOfWeek(#2018-10-03#)
01/10/2018
```

Here, the function tests whether the number of days to be subtracted in order to obtain the first day of your `Thursday->Wednesday` week would be less than the number of days into the current month, and if so, returns the first of the current month.

The expression `DateAdd("d", 1 - Day(datRef), datRef)` could alternatively be written `DateSerial(Year(datRef), Month(datRef), 1)` to obtain the same result.

---

**Last of Week**

```
Function LastOfWeek(datRef As Date) As Date
    LastOfWeek = DateAdd("d", 7 - Weekday(datRef, vbThursday), datRef)
    If Day(datRef) > Day(LastOfWeek) Then
        LastOfWeek = DateSerial(Year(datRef), Month(datRef) + 1, 0)
    End If
End Function
```

*Some examples*:

```
?LastOfWeek(#2018-10-04#)
10/10/2018 

?LastOfWeek(#2018-10-03#)
03/10/2018 

?LastOfWeek(#2018-09-27#)
30/09/2018
```

Similar to the first function, this function first calculates the date of the following `Wednesday` and then checks whether the day number of this date is less than that of the supplied date (indicating that it has strayed into the following month). If so, the last day in the current month is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is perfect and work as best as you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check to see if the output month matches the input month. To avoid continuously assigning a value to `GetFirstofWeek`, I created a `Temp` date for your initial calculation. Assign your output once the validation is complete.

To call an Excel function from Access, create an instance of `Excel.Application` as explained by @ComputerVersteher (*Thank you*)

**Note:** Do not use this from excel due to the presence of the created object. Code is intended to be ran from Access.

---

```
Option Explicit

Function GetFirstofWeek(dtDate As Date)

Dim Temp As Date

'Temp = DateAdd("d", dtDate, -(Weekday(dtDate)) + 1)
Temp = DateAdd("d", dtDate, -(Weekday(dtDate, vbThursday) - 1))

If Month(Temp) = Month(dtDate) Then
    GetFirstofWeek = Temp
Else
    Dim obj as Object: Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    GetFirstofWeek = obj.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Temp, 0) + 1
    Set obj = Nothing
End If

End Function
```

```
Function GetLastofWeek(dtDate) As Date

Dim Temp As Date

Temp = DateAdd("d", dtDate, (7 - (Weekday(dtDate, vbWednesday)) + 1))

If Month(Temp) = Month(dtDate) Then
    GetLastofWeek = Temp
Else
    Dim obj as Object: Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    GetLastofWeek = obj.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Temp, 0)
    Set obj = Nothing
End If

End Function
```